# Queries in MS Access 2003

Tags: ms-access

I am working on a database for a small hotel. Once a guest gets a room reserved they are given a parking lot card that needs to be returned as the guest check-out. I need help on  writing a query that would let the user know that Parking Lot card 01 (or any card #, that has already been given out to a guest) is unavailable. Can anyone please help me set this up. Thanks.

Tbls used

*Guest tbl*
GuestID PK
Check in date
Check out date
Room #
Room Type
Access Key Id

*Access Key tbl*
Access Key ID PK
Distributed - yes or no

Comment: We would need some idea of the table structure you are using to store this information to be able to query it.

Comment: Where are you storing the information about the cards that are given out? Which tables are involved?

Answer (score 2):

From your tables it seems that it is possible to get the room access key, and if Access Key table hold parking lot cards, it is possible to get that information, but these tables could be better structured.

```
 SELECT [Access Key ID] 
 FROM [Access Key tbl] 
 WHERE Distributed = True
```

It is never a good idea to have spaces in table names or field names, because it just leads to stress remembering to put square brackets round everything.

Consider a table set up like so:

```
Guests
GuestID
Etc.

Cards
CardID
CardType (Room or Parking)

CardsIssued
CardID
GuestID
IssueDate
ReturnDate
```

Answer (score 0):

The details you give do not specify any relationships so based on the information you have provided I am assuming that all you want to be able to do is tell which keys are available/unavailable at any given time.

For starters you can use the following query to list all keys that have *not* been distributed.

```
SELECT tblKey.KeyID, tblKey.Distributed
FROM tblKey
WHERE (((tblKey.Distributed)=False));
```

Change the *=False* to *=True* to reverse the logic and show all cards that *have* been distributed.

If you want to look for a *specific* key ID to find out if it has been distributed or not use the following:

```
SELECT tblKey.KeyID, tblKey.Distributed
FROM tblKey
WHERE (((tblKey.KeyID)=[Enter Key ID]));
```

This will present the user with a window where the key ID can be entered. Query Parameters are explained in greater detail [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/use-parameters-in-queries-and-reports-HA010096314.aspx)

Comment: How could I use this query within my form? If I have a combo box with all the Card #s listed on my form, I need the user to be able to query which cards have not been distributed and issue those to new guest.

Comment: This is a broad question (and somewhat outside the scope of the original question) as there are numerous ways to approach this E.G. the row source of the combo box could be based on the query so that it only lists the available key IDs to the user.